# Django querying on model which is involved in generic relation

Tags: sql, django, django-models, querying

Here I have 2 models, *Company* and *UserSupervision*. *Company* is related as a foreign key with generic relation model *UserSupervision*.

I want to have a query as following:

```
Company.objects.filter(**{'usersupervision__content_type': Company,
                          'usersupervision__user': some_user,
                          'usersupervision__date_cancelled': None})
```

So, I want to get all companies of **some_user** appeared in *UserSupervision* model. I know that *Company* and *UserSupervision* are not directly related, so i thought, maybe i have to use raw sql with joins? Or any other more appropriate solution?

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(blank=True, editable=False, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)

    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='companies', through='CompanyMembership')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('created date', blank=True, editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField('updated date', blank=True, editable=False, auto_now=True)


class UserSupervision(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    supervision = models.ForeignKey(Supervision, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.UUIDField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()

    date_assigned = models.DateTimeField('assigned date', blank=True, editable=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_cancelled = models.DateTimeField('cancelled date', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to find all the Companies in UserSupervision for a certian UserSupervision.user? Something like:

```
user_supervisions = UserSupervision.objects.filter(
    content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Company),
    user=some_user,
    date_cancelled=None
).order_by('content_type_id', 'object_id').distinct('content_type_id', 'object_id')

companies = [us.object_id for us in usersupervisions]  # Loop to create list of company ids.
```

You can [drop the order_by and distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) if you're not using PostgreSQL, but the companies loop would need to be changed to account for duplicate entries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I wanted to have querying method or raw-sql method, because, first fetching from database and again filtering with python is time and memory consuming job, I knew that i could do it with this kind of simple wrangling around, but it would be more concise and accurate if only one time querying with filtering is made, anyway thanks:)